# Updating a value in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My program is an inventory of items. Each item is input by the user until it reaches 10, then the total cost (cost * quantity) for each item is displayed at the end.

But I need to be able to update the quantity of a specific item. So I'm looking to somehow ask the user "which item do you want to update?" and "how much do you want to subtract" but I don't know how to link the item to its specific quantity. After that, I want to show the updated list of items again and the updated total cost.

Is it possible to do as an `ArrayList`? Or should I use a different structure?

So here's the class:

```
public class StockItem {
String stockItemID;
String stockItemDescription;
double stockItemCostPrice;
double stockItemSellingPrice;
int stockItemQuantityAvailable;
String toString;
int updateItemQuantityAvailable;

StockItem(String stockItemID, String stockItemDescription, double stockItemCostPrice,
double stockItemSellingPrice, int stockItemQuantityAvailable, int
updateItemQuantityAvailable) {
    this.stockItemID = stockItemID;
    this.stockItemDescription = stockItemDescription;
    this.stockItemCostPrice = stockItemCostPrice;
    this.stockItemSellingPrice = stockItemSellingPrice;
    this.stockItemQuantityAvailable = stockItemQuantityAvailable;
    this.updateItemQuantityAvailable = updateItemQuantityAvailable;
}

public void setStockItemID(String stockItemID) {
    this.stockItemID = stockItemID;
}

public String getStockItemID() {
    return stockItemID;
}

public void setStockItemDescription(String stockItemDescription) {
    this.stockItemDescription = stockItemDescription;
}

public String getStockItemDescription() {
    return stockItemDescription;
}

public void setStockItemCostPrice(double stockItemCostPrice) {
    this.stockItemCostPrice = stockItemCostPrice;
}

public double getStockItemCostPrice() {
    return stockItemCostPrice;
}

public void setStockItemSellingPrice(double stockItemSellingPrice) {
    this.stockItemSellingPrice = stockItemSellingPrice;
}

public double getStockItemSellingPrice() {
    return stockItemSellingPrice;
}

public void setStockItemQuantityAvailable(int stockItemQuantityAvailable) {
    this.stockItemQuantityAvailable = stockItemQuantityAvailable;
}

public int getStockItemQuantityAvailable() {
    return stockItemQuantityAvailable;
}

public String toString() {
    return (stockItemID + "\t" + stockItemDescription + "\t" + " Cost Price: $" + stockItemCostPrice + "\t" + "Selling Price: $" + stockItemSellingPrice + "\t" + "Quantity: " + stockItemQuantityAvailable + "\n");
}

public void setUpdateItemQuantityAvailable(int updateItemQuantityAvailable){
    this.updateItemQuantityAvailable = updateItemQuantityAvailable;
}
public int getUpdateItemQuantityAvailable() {
    return updateItemQuantityAvailable;
}
```

And then the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<StockItem> list = new ArrayList<StockItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        System.out.print(" Enter ID: ");
        String stockItemID = input.next();

        System.out.print(" Enter Item Description: ");
        String stockItemDescription = input.next();

        System.out.print(" Enter Item Cost Price: ");
        double stockItemCostPrice = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(" Enter Item Selling Price: ");
        double stockItemSellingPrice = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print(" Enter Item Quantity Available: ");
        int stockItemQuantityAvailable = input.nextInt();

        int updateItemQuantityAvailable = (0);

        list.add(new StockItem(stockItemID, stockItemDescription, stockItemCostPrice, stockItemSellingPrice, stockItemQuantityAvailable, updateItemQuantityAvailable));
        list.
    }

    System.out.println(list.toString().replace("]", "").replace("[", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ",""));

    for (StockItem data : list) {
        double totalStockCost = (data.getStockItemQuantityAvailable()- data.getUpdateItemQuantityAvailable()) * (data.getStockItemCostPrice());
        System.out.println(("Total Cost for ") + data.getStockItemDescription() + ": $" + totalStockCost);            
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just concerned about being able to update elements of the `List`, yes, you can do that.  For example, if you have filled `list` with 10 `StockItem`s, all with a `stockItemQuantityAvailable` of 100, and the user wants to buy 5 of the first item:

```
 StockItem chosen = list.get(0);
 int currentStock = chosen.getStockItemQuantityAvailable();
 chosen.setStockItemQuantityAvailable(currentStock - 5);
```

now if you print out the list, you'll find that there is 95 of the first item and 100 of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a `HashMap` rather than `ArrayList`. if by *"updating"* you mean *replacing*, then this should work:

```
HashMap<String, StockItem> map = new HashMap<String, StockItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    System.out.print(" Enter ID: ");
    String stockItemID = input.next();
    ...

    StockItem item = new StockItem(stockItemID, stockItemDescription, stockItemCostPrice, stockItemSellingPrice, stockItemQuantityAvailable, updateItemQuantityAvailable);
    map.put(stockItemID, item); // this line will replace any earlier item with same stockItemID
}
```

to display contents of the map:

```
for(StockItem item : map.values()) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

to display total cost of each item:

```
for(StockItem data : map.values()) {
    double totalStockCost = ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that will only work if StockItem implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` to look at the stockItemId.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap will make the searches more efficient.

If you didn't want to use HashMap, then the way I would approach this is to have a separate classes for the StockItem and a ShoppingCart class. In ShoppingCart, you could write a utlity method such as the below. Alternatively, you could also implement a Comparator and use List.contains().

```
ShoppingCart
    private List<StockItem> items = new ArrayList<StockItem>();

    public void updateQuantity(String itemId, int qty) {
        if(null == itemId) { return; }

        for(StockItem item : items) {
            if (itemId.equals(item.getStockItemID())){
                item.setStockItemQuantityAvailable(qty);
            }
        }
    }
```